# unable to find the solution using mathematica function ''GreenFunction"

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, special-functions, symbols

```
GreenFunction[{u''''[x] - b^4*u[x], u''[0] == 0, u'''[0] == 0, 
  u''[1] == 0, u'''[1] == 0}, u[x], {x, 0, 1}, y]
```

Actually, i am trying to find the green function of a linear fourth order differential equation using Mathematica. But seems like I am not getting any results by using Mathematica predefined function "GreenFunction "

Answer (score 3):

Up to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function), the Green function $G(x,y)$ of the linear differential operator `L = u''''[x] - b^4*u[x]` can be treated as any solution of the ODE

```
DSolve[u''''[x] - b^4*u[x] == DiracDelta[y - x], u[x], x]
```

> {{u[x] -> 
>      E^(-b x) C[2] + E^(b x) C[4] + C[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) Cos[b x] + C[3] Sin[b x] - (1/(
>       4 b^3))E^(-b x - 
>         b y) (E^(2 b x)
>            HeavisideTheta[
>            y - x HeavisideTheta[1 - x] - 
>             HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] HeavisideTheta[-y + 
>             HeavisideTheta[1 - x] + x HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] - 
>          E^(2 b y)
>            HeavisideTheta[
>            y - x HeavisideTheta[1 - x] - 
>             HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] HeavisideTheta[-y + 
>             HeavisideTheta[1 - x] + x HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] - 
>          2 E^(2 b x)
>            HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] HeavisideTheta[
>            y - x HeavisideTheta[1 - x] - 
>             HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] HeavisideTheta[-y + 
>             HeavisideTheta[1 - x] + x HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] + 
>          2 E^(2 b y)
>            HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] HeavisideTheta[
>            y - x HeavisideTheta[1 - x] - 
>             HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] HeavisideTheta[-y + 
>             HeavisideTheta[1 - x] + x HeavisideTheta[-1 + x]] + 
>          2 E^(b x + b y) Cos[b y] HeavisideTheta[x - y] Sin[b x] - 
>          2 E^(b x + b y) Cos[b x] HeavisideTheta[x - y] Sin[b y])}}

However, Mathematica uses a slight modification of the above definition:

```
DSolve[u''''[x] - b^4*u[x] == DiracDelta[x - y], u[x], x]
```

> {{u[x] -> 
>      E^(-b x) C[2] + E^(b x) C[4] + C[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) Cos[b x] + C[3] Sin[b x] - (1/(
>       4 b^3))E^(-b x - b y)
>         HeavisideTheta[
>         x - y] (-E^(2 b x) + E^(2 b y) + 
>          2 E^(b x + b y) Cos[b y] Sin[b x] - 
>          2 E^(b x + b y) Cos[b x] Sin[b y])}}

I am not a specialist in ODEs so I am sorry if I am mistaken.

Comment: What is that C[2], C[3] is. They are integration constant?

Comment: @Vijay Kumar S: The notations C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4] stand for arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 0):

GreenFunction[] gives no result because your boundary conditions `u''''[1]==0` are of the same order as the ode is!!

With correct bc you can calculate greens function using DSolveValue

```
green = Simplify@DSolveValue[{u''''[x] - b^4*u[x] == DiracDelta[x - y] ,u''[0] == 1,u'''[0] == 0, u''[1] == 0, u''' [1] == 0}, u , {x, 0, 1}]
(* green[x] *)
```

Don't know why GreenFunction[] doesn't work...

Comment: sorry it is third order boundary condition  , but still it don't work

Comment: All your bc ==0 and you expect a non vanishing solution?

Comment: yes, is it not possible? I guess  it is possible

Comment: You're right, sorry my  answer was to fast!